# rs.initiate crashes mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I'm running into an issue where calling rs.initiate() crashes the mongodb server:

```
mongodb  | ############## 1 ######################
mongodb  | MongoServerError: This node was not started with replication enabled.
mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2024-02-15T14:45:59.613+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn13","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:57268","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"14a10ead-f3a9-4b34-a054-16458c102c8b"}},"connectionId":13,"connectionCount":4}}
mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2024-02-15T14:45:59.613+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn12","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:57264","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"78b7e779-c5ba-4ef9-927b-4bbdf00c78c3"}},"connectionId":12,"connectionCount":3}}
mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2024-02-15T14:45:59.613+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn10","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:57246","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"0183b0ca-8220-4e75-be58-4ed280c066ce"}},"connectionId":10,"connectionCount":2}}
mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2024-02-15T14:45:59.613+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn9","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:57244","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"93a6213a-b6e9-40ec-9d76-d148ecbf1f09"}},"connectionId":9,"connectionCount":1}}
mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2024-02-15T14:45:59.613+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn11","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:57260","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"e323c3de-3c86-4eea-8d45-c87b2b3016f7"}},"connectionId":11,"connectionCount":0}}
mongodb exited with code 1
```

docker-compose:

```
  mongo:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./mongodb
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./db/mongo:/data/db
      - ./mongodb/init/startup.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup.js:ro
      - ./mongodb/mongo.conf:/etc/mongo.conf:ro
    env_file: .env
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
    command: ["--replSet", "dbrs", "--bind_ip_all","--config", "/etc/mongo.conf"]
```

startup.js :

```
print("############## 1 ######################");
rs.initiate()
print("############## 2 ######################");
```

mongo.conf:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /keyfile
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:latest

ENV TZ="Etc/UTC"
ENV TIME_ZONE="Etc/UTC"

RUN apt update
RUN apt install openssl
RUN apt-get clean

RUN openssl rand -base64 741 > /keyfile
RUN chmod 600 /keyfile
RUN chown 999:999 /keyfile
```

I'm hitting a roadblock, can anyone help ?

Comment: In general I recommend not mixing [command line options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-file-settings-command-line-options-mapping/) an [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) Use only one of them.

Comment: thank you for your help, i narrowed it down to docker init script that overrides my arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It seems due to some reason your mongod process do not see the --replSet command line option , perhaps execute from shell the following command to confirm what the mongod process see:

```
db.adminCommand( { getCmdLineOpts: 1 } )
```

Usually the command line options takes precedence over the configuration file settings...

Comment: I guess he cannot run the command if the MongoDB server does not start :-)

Comment: Indeed you are right , I have wrongly assumed the mongod process is started but only crashing when rs.initiate() is executed , but yeah the rs.initiate() is inside the startup.js so perhaps he can update this script with the above command to see what the mongod interpret ...